# Como melhorar esse: Hell callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async

Estou terminando o desenvolvimento de um sistema de anúncios, o sistema usa o servidor redis para salvar dados e exibir campanhas diretamente da memória ram, uma vez que a patologia desses sistemas requerem muito consumo de disco. A cada x tempo eu preciso obter os valores espalhados através de coleções no meu servidor redis e salvar em duas tabelas relacionais no meu servidor mysql. No entanto, sou novo demais para programação assíncrona e não domino as promessas, embora o código abaixo pareça funcionar bem. Eu não gostaria de deixá-lo com esta redação, porque se torna difícil a manutenção do código.

Essa rotina insere o custo de cada campanha, incluindo conexões de usuários, impressões de campanhas e cliques em anúncios em sites afiliados. Em outras palavras, preciso de um loop para cada zona criada pelos editores, somando o número de conexões existentes nessas zonas, em seguida adiciono a essa coleção as impressões e cliques de cada campanha e envio sobre intervalos de 15 segundos para o mysql servidor.

```
SalvarStatsCustosCampanha = function(){
  cliente_redis.smembers("campanhas_disponiveis",function(err,campanhas){
    var multi                                    = cliente_redis.multi();
    for(var i= 0; i<campanhas.length;i++){
      multi.smembers("zona_membros_campanhas:"+campanhas[i]);
    }
    multi.exec(function(err,zonas){
      async.forEachOf(zonas,function(lista,indice,callback){
        var desconectados                        = 0;
        var conectados                           = 0;
        async.each(lista,function(zona,fn){
          desconectados                         += (typeof(global.desconectados_zona[zona]) != 'undefined')? global.desconectados_zona[zona] : 0;
          conectados                            += (typeof(global.conectados_zona[zona])    != 'undefined')? global.conectados_zona[zona]    : 0;
          fn();
        },function(err){
          cliente_redis.hmget("campanha:"+campanhas[indice],['id_usuario','cliques','impressoes','custo'],function(err,info){
            let campanha                         = {};
            campanha.id_anunciante               = info[0];
            campanha.id_campanha                 = campanhas[indice];
            campanha.conectados                  = desconectados;
            campanha.impressoes                  = (info[2] == null)? 0 : info[2];
            campanha.cliques                     = (info[1] == null)? 0 : info[1];
            campanha.custo                       = (info[3] == null)? 0 : info[3];
            if(campanha.cliques                 == 0){
              campanha.ctr                       = 0;
              campanha.ctr                       = campanha.ctr.toFixed(3);
            }else campanha.ctr                   = (parseFloat(campanha.cliques) / parseFloat(campanha.conectados)).toFixed(3);
            campanha.data                        = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            campanha.fechamento                  = moment().format();
            var data                             = {};
            data.campanha                        = campanha;
            data.data                            = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            fnCampanha.GetCustoCampanhaDia(data,function(data,custo){
              CampanhaSangria                    = function(campanha){
                cliente_redis.hmset("campanha:"+campanha.id_campanha,{"cliques": 0,"custo" : 0,"impressoes": 0});
              }
              if(typeof(custo) != 'undefined'){
                data.campanha.id_custo           = custo.id_custo;
                fnCustos.AlterarCustos(data.campanha,CampanhaSangria);
              }else{
                fnCustos.AdicionarCustos(data.campanha,CampanhaSangria);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

A mesma lógica é empregada para as zonas de campanhas responsáveis ​​por vincular os anúncios nos sites afiliados, apenas o número de impressões não é computado porque a zona recebe por soquete em tempo real dezenas de campanhas então eu só efetivo a contabilização de impressões para campanhas.

```
SalvarStatsRendimentosZona = function(){
  cliente_redis.smembers('zonas_disponiveis',function(err,zonas){
    if(zonas.length > 0){
      Falha                                       = function(){
        console.log("O processo de update de rendimentos falhou");
      }
      Sucesso                                     = function(data,zona){
        cliente_redis.hmget("zona:"+data.zona.id_zona,['cliques','rendimentos'],function(err,cliques){
          if(cliques != null){
            let rendimento                        = {};
            rendimento.conectados                 = (!isNaN(global.desconectados_zona[zona.id_zona]))? global.desconectados_zona[zona.id_zona]: 0;
            /* Se não houver conexões sobre a zona no dia corrente não há necessidade de alterar ou inserir apenas ignoramos
            esse registro até que alguma conexão exista */
            if(parseInt(rendimento.conectados) > 0){
              rendimento.id_zona                  = zona.id_zona;
              rendimento.id_publicador            = zona.id_publicador;
              rendimento.cliques                  = cliques[0];
              if(rendimento.cliques              == 0){
                rendimento.ctr                    = 0;
                rendimento.ctr                    = rendimento.ctr.toFixed(3);
              }else rendimento.ctr                = (parseFloat(rendimento.cliques) / parseFloat(rendimento.conectados)).toFixed(3);
              rendimento.ganhos                   = parseFloat(cliques[1]).toFixed(3);
              rendimento.fechamento               = moment().format();
              data.rendimento                     = rendimento;
              data.data                           = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
              fnRendimento.GetRendimentosZonaDia(data,function(data,rendimentos){
                ZonaSangria                       = function(){
                  cliente_redis.hmset("zona:"+data.zona.id_zona,{"cliques": 0,"rendimentos" : 0});
                  cliente_redis.hmset("stats:zonas:"+data.zona.id_zona,{"desconectados" : 0});
                  global.desconectados_zona[data.zona.id_zona] = 0;
                }
                data.rendimento.data              = data.data;
                if(typeof(rendimentos)           != 'undefined'){
                  data.rendimento.id_rendimento   = rendimentos.id_rendimento;
                  fnRendimento.AlterarRendimento(data.rendimento);
                  ZonaSangria();
                }else{
                  fnRendimento.AdicionarRendimentos(data.rendimento);
                  ZonaSangria();
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
      zonas.forEach(function(id_zona){
        var data                              = {};
        data.zona                             = {};
        data.debug                            = 'zonas disponiveis';
        data.zona.id_zona                     = id_zona;
        data.sucesso                          = Sucesso;
        data.sucesso_redis                    = Sucesso;
        data.falha                            = Falha;
        fnZona.GetZonaById(data);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Finalmente, tenho que executar essas duas rotinas simultaneamente para evitar limpar a variável ​​global do script que mantém o número de visitantes desconectados antes de salvar no meu banco de dados, uma vez que após salvar nas duas tabelas eu atribuo zero a ela, em cada zona de campanha. Perder as desconexões seria risco para o cálculo estatístico do aplicativo. Preciso impedir que o evento de desconexão do soquete confunda os resultados que estão sendo salvos no banco de dados quando meu setInterval rodar porque se trata de uma variável de scopo global, por isso usei o padrão novo async await alterando a versão do meu servidor de node.js de 6 para 8, para simplificar a codificação e rodar simultaneamente as funções. Como posso melhorar este código? Eu gostaria de algo na vertical que me permitisse uma melhor manutenção do código no futuro.

```
setInterval(function(){
  async function ExecuteActions(){
    await SalvarStatsCustosCampanha();
    await SalvarStatsRendimentosZona();
  }
  ExecuteActions();
},configs.ttl_save_stats);
```

Sei que a pergunta é abrangente e demanda tempo de análise mais qualquer opinião me seria válida!

[image]

Comment: Você está usando pelo menos a versão 8 do Node?

Comment: Sim, instalei ela ontem. Mas o código foi todo desenvolvido na versão 6. Portanto eu não tinha suporte a  async e await.

Comment: A partir da versão 8 você pode usar `async` e `await`, o que vai facilitar muito a manutenção e entendimento do código. Se for possível utilizar essa versão eu posso reescrever o código para você usando as funcionalidades novas do `ECMAScript` e aplicando o padrão do `AirBNB` de codificação em `Javascript`

Comment: Se você me der um simples exemplo de funcionamento, já me ajudaria muito não precisa ser exatamente seguindo o meu código pode ser uma breve explicação sobre o funcionamento do async e await. Ontem eu analisei a documentação mas não me parece abrangente de exemplos.

Comment: Então, é que na realidade tem bastante coisa que você pode melhorar no seu código, aí acho que fica mais fácil extrair os conceitos e reescrever. Uma coisa, por exemplo, é que você está fazendo tudo em uma função só e isso já aumenta bastante a complexidade. Tem várias coisas que dá pra melhorar e eu escrever uma resposta completa sobre isso, mas pra isso preciso saber se a versão 8 vai estar disponível ou não

Comment: Sim atualizei ontem meu servidor para a versão 8

Comment: Recomendo que você tente reduzir a pergunta a um exemplo mais simples, algo que demonstre seu problema sem toda essa complexidade da sua aplicação. Seria especialmente útil se você conseguisse postar algo que fosse "executável" localmente, por exemplo um código que popula o Redis e permite rodar seu código. As chances de você receber boas respostas seriam bem maiores com algo assim.

Comment: O código funciona perfeitamente, só que é exatamente a complexidade que gerou o hell callback, preciso de uma forma mais funcional de escrever isso sem tanta confusão nos escopos para me facilitar futuramente a manutenção. Mesmo com o advento do async e await não tenho a manha de como modularizar isso de forma que tenha acesso as variáveis em cada escopo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos resolver o problema do seu `setInterval`. Para garantir que não existirá duas execuções simultâneas do mesmo código, sugiro que altere para `setTimeout` e reinicie o contador após a execução da função raiz (prinicpal) da seguinte maneira:

```
const execucaoRaiz = async () => {
  try {
    // Garantirá que as duas funções executarão em paralelo
    const promessas = [
      salvarStatsCustosCampanha(),
      salvarStatsRendimentosZona(),
    ];

    // O código só prosseguirá quando as duas execuções forem completadas
    await Promise.all(promessas);

    // Eventual código adicional após a execução das duas funções principais
    // ...
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  // Garante que o timer será reiniciado mesmo que o código ocasione algum erro
  iniciarTimer();
};

const iniciarTimer = async () => {
  setTimeout(execucaoRaiz, configs.ttl_save_stats);
}

// Executará a primeira vez após o tempo determinado
iniciarTimer();
```

Logo após essa alteração, sugiro que utilize promessas no caso do `redis`. Não sei exatamente como é a execução do módulo, porém olhando no seu código acredito que a estrutura `callback` seja a convencionada pela comunidade do node (`function callback(erro, resultado) {}`). Sendo assim é possível utilizar a função [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) para transformá-las em promessas:

```
const { promisify } = require('utils');

// ...

const smembers = promisify(cliente_redis.smembers);

const campanhas = await smembers('campanhas_disponiveis');

// ...
```

Por fim transforme suas funções em `async` para que possa utilizar o `await` dentro delas:

```
const salvarStatsCustosCampanha = async () => {
  // Lógica da função
}
```

Será impressindível que você quebre o código em mais funções para facilitar o entendimento do mesmo em futuras manutenções.

Nos meus exemplos acima utilizei o [Style Guide do AirBNB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) como base. Segui-lo irá deixar o seu código mais limpo e legível e também aplicar algumas boas práticas a ele.

Descrevi em linhas gerais pois o seu código não é executável, portanto se torna difícil reescrevê-lo sem a possibilidade de testar o resultado.